# Can you override a class constructor and use inherited?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

When you define a class constructor in a base class (i.e. to set some static class variable), is it possible to override this class constructor in a derived class and call the constructor from its hierarchal parent with **inherited**?

Example:

```
TBaseclass = class(TObject)
public
   class constructor ClassCreate; virtual;
end;

TOtherClass = class(TBaseClass)
public
  class constructor ClassCreate; override;
end;

**implementation**

class constructor TBaseClass.ClassCreate;
begin
  //do some baseclass stuff
end;

class constructor TotherClass.ClassCreate;
begin
  inherited;
  //do some other stuff
end;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no reason for [class constructors](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Class_Constructors) to be virtual since they cannot be invoked polymorphically. You can't call them directly; the compiler inserts calls to them automatically based on which classes are used in a program. Virtual methods are for run-time polymorphism, but since the compiler knows exactly which class constructors it's invoking at compile time, there is no need for dynamic dispatch on class constructors or destructors.

Virtual methods aren't required for inheritance, however, so there should be no problem using `inherited` in a class constructor or class destructor. As [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11085158/33732) points out, though, the compiler ignores calls to `inherited` because it's generally unwise to initialize a class multiple times, which is what you'd be doing if you really managed to call the inherited class constructor. If there's something you need to happen twice, you'll need to find a different way to make it happen.

Comment: +1 for "the compiler inserts calls to them automatically based on which classes are used in a program". Class constructors mainly make smartlinking more efficient. (because the initialization of related vars becomes conditional on the class' use)

Comment: No, @Marjan. It wasn't an inexplicable vote. It was a vote by someone who mistook "class constructor" for "constructor" and then took exception to my and David's claims that they couldn't be virtual and would have no use if they could. Those with enough reputation can see the "rebuttal" answer that was later deleted because I pointed out the misunderstanding in terminology. The comments explaining the votes have been deleted already.

Comment: To be quite honest, the actual detail of the answer are way over my head, simply because I've never had to do such a thing. But Rob, +1, you are truly a master of explanation.

Comment: The official document explained the situation perfectly clear that a class constructor cannot be inherited.

Comment: @stanley the compiler also tells you

Comment: @RobKennedy: ah, spotted that answer after I commented, didn't read the comments...

Comment: @Stanley, where does the documentation explain that? There's no mention of inheritance in the "Class Constructors" section I linked to.

Answer (score 10):

For a start, since class constructors cannot be virtual (it makes no sense for them to be virtual), you need to remove the `virtual` and `override` keywords to make your code compile.

Class constructors are typically used to initialise class vars. Class vars typically need to be initialised once and once only. If you could call `inherited` in the way you suggest in the question, then `TBaseClass.ClassCreate` would be called multiple times when in fact it needs to be called exactly once.

Whilst you can write `inherited` in a class constructor, and the code will compile, the compiler just ignores it.

```
program ClassConstructors;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  Count: Integer;

type
  TBaseclass = class
  public
    class constructor ClassCreate;
  end;

  TOtherClass = class(TBaseClass)
  public
    class constructor ClassCreate;
  end;

class constructor TBaseClass.ClassCreate;
begin
  inc(Count);
end;

class constructor TotherClass.ClassCreate;
begin
  inherited;
end;

begin
  TBaseClass.Create.Free;
  TOtherClass.Create.Free;
  Writeln(Count);//outputs 1
  Readln;
end.
```

Note that, of course, both class constructors do run.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! But do `inherited` calls always get ignored by the compiler? I thought there are `inherited Create(AOwner)` appearances some where. Are there duplicate calls? Could you help to comment?

Comment: @XichenLi `inherited` gets ignored only when it makes no sense. For example class constructors. Or in methods that override abstract methods.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: overridden abstract methods do call inherited and produce an EAbstractError if/when you do `inherited SomeMethodName;` instead of just `inherited;`